# How do I define that value crosses 0 in C#?

Tags: c#, list

There is list of int variable

```
data = List<int>
```

It contains few ints above the 0, few int's under 0 and so on. Data looks like:

```
-2962
-5787
-1671
-5667
-498
-4463
1399
3608
2173
```

I need to find the first item, when this function crosses the 0 from + to - (or from - to +) to get only first items above 0 or first items under 0 (depends on the sign of first item if it + or -).

So my code is:

```
var itemSign = 0;

foreach (var item in data)
{
    if (itemSign == Sign(item))
    {
        result.Add(item);
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
    itemSign = Sign(item);
}
```

But output is:

```
-2962
-5787
-1671
-5667
-498
-4463
1399
3608
2173
```

It seems like it doesn't work at all because I need to get these ints in these case:

```
-2962
-5787
-1671
-5667
-498
-4463
```

How do I define that value crosses 0 in C#?

Comment: Well, look at your code. How long will the foreach loop run in your code (in other words: when will it stop attempting to add items to add to the result list), and thus how many and which of the list items will be considered for addition to the result list?

Comment: @elgonzo yes, but after -4463 I expected that itemSign == Sign(item) == false

Comment: Use the debugger to see and learn what your code is really doing. With this knowledge you should be able to modify your code to get the expected result. See here if you are unfamiliar with debugging: [Navigating through Code with the Debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger) and
[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want to check if itemSign isn't equal to the sign of the current item, not check if they are equal?

Comment: @Blam, no, this part of the code makes sense (except the initialization of itemSign). OP only wants to add items to the result list that have the same sign as the previous item, until the point in the number list where the sign changes the first time...

Comment: Sorry misread. If you need to end a loop, you can `break;` from it. You could also use a while loop instead, as you only want to loop until your condition is met?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use break as soon as sign change appears :

```
var itemSign = Sign(data.FirstOrDefault());
var result = new List<int>();
foreach (var item in data)
{
    if (itemSign == Sign(item))
    {
        result.Add(item);
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
    else
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it’s so succinctly!

Answer (score 1):

There are two versions I can think of. Both use the `List<int>.FindIndex()` method.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<int>() {
            -2962   ,
            -5787   ,
            -1671   ,
            -5667   ,
            -498    ,
            -4463   ,
            1399    ,
            3608    ,
            2173    ,
        };

        int index = list.FindIndex((x) => x>0)-1;
        // index = 5

        index=list.Zip(list.Skip(1), (x, y) => Math.Sign(x*y)).ToList().FindIndex((s) => s==-1);
        // index = 5
    }
}
```

The first one returns the index of the first non-negative number.

The second one multiplies consecutive numbers and if their product has a negative sign it means the numbers just changed sign.

Answer (score 0):

Usint `System.Linq` (just for fun)

```
var input = new List<int> { -2962, -5787, -1671, -5667, -498, -4463, 1399, 3608, 2173 };

var cross = input
    .Zip(input.Skip(1), (a, b) => new []{a,b})
    .TakeWhile(t => (t.First() ^ t.Last()) >> 31 == 0)
    .SelectMany(_ => _)
    .Distinct();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", cross)); //-2962,-5787,-1671,-5667,-498,-4463
```

If you want just the last element in the row, or first, then `Aggregate` could work:

```
var cross = input.Aggregate((a,b) => (a ^ b) >> 31 == 0 ? a : b); //1399
var cross = input.Aggregate((a,b) => (a ^ b) >> 31 == 0 ? b : a); //-4463
```

Answer (score -3):

for each element in list, if >0 add to positive list, if <0 add to negative list. this is simple if else stuff....

Comment: What if the values start negative, then become positive, then negative again? The OP wants just the first batch of negatives